# magento modify product url and name

Tags: url, name

i worte code to modify product name and url .

i am able to change name but url does not works below is mycode :

```
    public function modifyallname(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $products = $observer->getCollection();
        foreach( $products as $product )
        {
            $product->setUrlKey('111');
            $product->setName($product->getName().' & '.$pricetoadd->getName().' '.$customprice);
        }
   }
```

Comment: To change URL, Run indexing for url

Comment: can you remove cache?

Comment: not work :(......

Answer (score 1):

Fix this issue. Do following thing

1. To change URL,  Run indexing for url
2. Clear cache

Hope this works

Comment: not works bro..

Comment: sorry not mispelt as now